# Error On Setting The Property MaximizedBounds in c# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

Error On Setting The Property MaximizedBounds in c# WinForm

Cannot format the value to the desired type.

when i am setting the value

```
        MaximizedBounds = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
```

and running the application i am getting the error

> Cannot format the value to the desired type.

Comment: What is the error ? Are you using System.Windows.Forms ? Because your method is working (TESTED)

Comment: @Sourabh Devpura, show the code where you are setting it

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
MaximizedBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0,
    Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Width,
    Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Height);
```